# Check()-ing package failed because of @example

Tags: r, package, cran

I have created my own R package that is supposed to be submited to CRAN. Documentation and other stuff is generated with Roxygen from the following R file:

```
#' Measure stability of features in time
#'
#' This function computes IGR for each sliding window of given size. 
#' @param data A matrix or a data frame with attribute-value structure (attributes in columns and samples in rows). Only label attribute can be named "label".
#' @param time A column index or column name in the data, which defines sample ordering. The attribute must be numeric.
#' @param label A column index or column name in the data, which holds the target value.
#' @param window_size_ratio A ratio of the count of samples in the sliding window to the count of samples in the data. The default is 0.3.
#' @param window_count Count of the used sliding windows. The default is 10. 
#' @return igr - A matrix with the Information Gain Ratio for each attribute (in the column) in the given sliding window (in the row).
#'         The column names are inherited from the data. Sliding windows are sorted by time ascendingly. 
#'          sample_count - A vector with the count of samples in each sliding window.
#'          or
#'          NA - In case of error 
#' @import caret ggplot2
#' @examples 
#'  result <- time.igr(ggplot2::mpg, 'year', 'class')






time.igr <- function(data, time, label, window_size_ratio=0.3, window_count=10) {

    # Initialization

    sample_cnt = nrow(data)
    att_cnt = ncol(data)

and so on...
```

But something is wrong with @example section, because when i run check() command, I got the following result:

```
* checking Rd cross-references ... OK
* checking for missing documentation entries ... OK
* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... OK
* checking Rd \usage sections ... OK
* checking Rd contents ... OK
* checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
* checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in 'prediction.stability.in.time-Ex.R' failed
The error most likely occurred in:

> base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
> ### Name: time.igr
> ### Title: Measure stability of features in time
> ### Aliases: time.igr
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
>  result <- time.igr(ggplot2::mpg, 'year', 'class')
Error: could not find function "time.igr"
Execution halted
* checking PDF version of manual ... OK
* DONE

Status: 1 ERROR
See
  'C:/Users/ondrnovy/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpoHMRTD/prediction.stability.in.time.Rcheck/00check.log'
for details.

Error: Command failed (1)
```

What is wrong? After removing the @example, check() command is ok, but I heard that, this type of error is a serious problem with package and removing the @example section is not solution.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. From your code, the `@export` part is missing in the roxygen comments, so the function is not exported and `R` can't find it.

Comment: Hmm, not that obvious actually, since in my case the names are all exported by default anyway. This only happens when you add `roxygen` examples somehow. I would like to upvote this answer, but it is hidden in the comment.

Comment: I have the very same problem. It works fine if I check interactively, but fails on command line. Everything is exported. Is there any news here?

Answer (score 3):

One solution to similar errors is to add example in a dontrun chunk:

```
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' sum("a")
#' }
```

or:

> Instead of including examples directly in the documentation, you can
>   put them in separate files and use @example
>   path/relative/to/package/root to insert them into the documentation.
>   (Note that the @example tag here has no ‘s’.)

Source: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-functions

Also if using `document()` and having manually edited `NAMESPACE`, it will not be re-generated.

EDIT: Cran reviewer discourages use of dontrun: (email)

> dontrun{}   should be only used if the example really cannot be executed (e.g. because of missing additional   software, missing API
>   keys, ...) by the user.   That's why wrapping examples in \dontrun{}
>   adds the   comment ("# Not run:") as a warning for the   user. Please
>   unwrap the examples if they are   executable in < 5 sec, or create additionally small toy examples to allow automatic testing (then replace \dontrun with \donttest). You could also replace \dontrun{} with \donttest, but it would be 
>   preferable to have automatic checks for functions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. If anyone is still looking for a solution, I just had the same problem and fixed. The issue is in the function name - don't use dots to separate words, use underscores.

When roxygenize creates your documentation files, it will probably add something like this:

```
\method{extract}{sentiments}(df)
```

So it automatically separates the words. Instead, if you use underscore, your documentation file will not include the \method part for some reason.
This corrected the issue on my end.

Note: My other functions still use dot instead of underscores - but they somehow didn't cause roxygenize to create that \method line above in the rd documentations in the man folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue what a blank too many!

WRONG:

```
#' \dontrun {
```

**GOOD**

```
#' \dontrun{
```